# Postinstall script not executing after publish

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts, npm-publish, npm-package

None of my scripts are working after publishing an npm package. I will try to give a simple example here to demonstrate the point.

The package.json scripts object (relevant parts) looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "install": "node scripts/install.js",
  "postinstall": "npx prisma generate"
}
```

The scripts/install.js looks like this:

```
function main() {
    console.log('hello world')
    process.exit(0);
}

main();
```

This works when I execute:

`$ npm i`

inside the package that I am publishing.

When I install it locally it works too:

```
$ npm i
$ npm run build
$ npm pack --pack-destination
```

After the pack, in another project, I specify the path to the tar file generated & everything works!

If I run:
`$ npm publish`

& then install it inside the same project that consumes the node_module, it does not execute the install or postinstall script.

To debug this, I run the command:
`npm i --foreground-scripts`

and have tried
`npm i --foreground-scripts --loglevel verbose`
as well to better understand the problem.

The documentation for the npm lifecycle is lacking & I could not find any information online. Please note that this package is publish in a private gitlab registry and I am able to download & "install" the package as I see it in my node_modules but it does run the lifecycle scripts when installing remotely from npm.

I do have an .npmrc file specified.

This is my first post & I hope I have been descriptive & clear. Any help would be appreciated :).

Update: This works on npm 6.14.2. It looks like this issue started in npm 7 & persists in npm 8.

Update: To test this idea, I installed https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-lifecycle-hooks! & it ran the lifecycle methods! Then I copied the package contents to a new folder & published it as a scoped package in the GitLab NPM Registry & then it did not run any lifecycle methods!

Comment: I would like to add that I am using a Mac. This issue occurs on both my iMac 2019 & MacBook Pro both running npm 8.8.0

Comment: If you `cd` to the project directory that’s consuming the package that you published (I.e. the project folder where you are trying to install the package that you published) and run `npm config get ignore-script` what does if return - _true_ or _false_ ?

Comment: I get undefined so that would be a falsy value

Comment: Yes, however It’s worth running `npm config set ignore-script false` for good measure as its value should be a [Boolean](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install#ignore-scripts)

Comment: Sure, I set it to false. Still no luck

Comment: All the other scripts execute except the one that was installed from the GitLab registry. If I install it locally, it executes the postinstall just fine!